# How to implement QR Code scanner in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, qr-code, blazor-webassembly

I found this project in github `ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner` and install the package using nugget package manager

After installing and running the website there was an error

> http://localhost:5196/dashboard/_content/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner.lib.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5196/dashboard/_content/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner.lib.module.js

I tried adding it to `index.html` but still getting the same error

Git repo of QRcode scanner

https://github.com/YannVasseur35/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner

Comment: You will probably need to post your project on GitHub in order for someone else to help. I tried the package locally with a Blazor WebAssembly App and it works fine.